# Hiding the first tab of accordion panel in JSF Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, tabs, primefaces, accordion

By default the first tab of the primefaces accordion panel is shown open on page load. Is there a way that it can be closed on page load.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach is to define a widgetVar:

```
<p:accordionPanel widgetVar="accordion">
    ...
</p:accordionPanel>
```

And then:

```
<body onload="PF('accordion').unselect(0)">
```

or for older PF versions:

```
<body onload="accordion.unselect(0)">
```

Comment: Thanks .. I tried the first approach. It works. The tab is closed by default. But there is one problem. It does not get loaded on click. The remaining tabs gets updated from db(any time we click on it) . But first tab doesnt work this way. It stays empty. Any idea why this is happening. The control passes to bean on clikc and even the value is loaded,but it is not reflected in tab.

Comment: You are right... I tested it with attribute `dynamic="true"`. Then the first tab won't get loaded if you click it. I'll adapt my answer. Use the approach with the widgetVar. There it works.

Comment: Still not working. The tab is open and is without data. I am keeping dynamic = "true". Also i am using facelets. Can that affect the results.

Comment: Thanking you after a long time! But this really saved my rear! The Primefaces folks really need to change the documentation to mention such tricks.

Comment: I would like an method in accordion like "collapseAll()" because  in the current version (4.0) only have "unselect(X)" where X is the index of the tab where you want to collapse.
I think it's a good detail for a new version.

Comment: @AlvaroCachoperro You're right, the `widgetVar.collapseAll()` is gone. I tried to bring some attention about it in the following issue : https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1039

Answer (score 20):

You can just do

```
<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="-1">
```

Comment: It expands the second tab

Comment: Works for me, with PF 5.0. Doesn't expand the second tab.

Answer (score 7):

It works if you set activeIndex to blank (Primefaces 3.4.1).

```
<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="">
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the posted answered worked for me in PrimeFaces 3.5.x. using multiple mode, but this:

```
<p:accordionPanel multiple="true" activeIndex="null" ... >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the PF function, as the code below:

```
PF('accordionWidgetVarName').unselect(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering for PrimeFaces 6.0 users:

You can set the widgetVar property and then call PF('widgetVarValue').unselect(0); as Fred Policarpo mentioned; however, I was not able to get this to work upon accordion **load**, and I tried various things like using a div's onload event, using a remoteCommand with autoRun enabled, and even using custom jQuery. None of these worked for the load event, only when I ran that PF unselect call in the console.

In PrimeFaces 6.0, you can use the activeIndex attribute and set it to multiple values, e.g. "1,3,5", to close all of the tabs but open the 2nd, 4th, and 6th tabs (base 0 indexing).