# Set Advanced Panel(Primefaces 3.0) by default in minimized state

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using a primefaces 2 Advanced panel in this way.

```
 <html>
    <h:body>
    <h:form>

    <p:panel header="Panel 1" toggleable="true"  widgetVar="panel1">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">  

               <h:outputText value="Type: *" />  
                          <h:outputText />  
               </h:panelGrid>  
        </p:panel>

        <p:panel header="Panel 2" toggleable="true"  widgetVar="panel2">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">  

               <h:outputText value="Type: *" />  
                          <h:outputText />  
               </h:panelGrid>  
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

I want to set by default panel in hide state, I also tried as here said 
[Hiding the first tab of accordion panel in JSF Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189246/hiding-the-first-tab-of-accordion-panel-in-jsf-primefaces)
    but did'nt worked,
I want to set panel 1 by default open and panel 2 as hidden.

How can do that? Any suggessions....

Comment: did you try combinations of toggleable="true" collapsed="true" closable="true" attributes ?