# can't get all p:accordionPanel tabs closed by default

Tags: primefaces, accordion

I can't get all p:accordionPanel tabs closed

I tried both solutions recommended in Question [Hiding the first tab of accordion panel in JSF Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10189246/999750)
but it does not work for me in case the value attribute of the accordionPanel is an EL expression. the first tab is always open.

I tried

```
<p:accordionPanel widgetVar="accordion" 
multiple="true" 
value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.getTabs()}" var="r">
```

without success

and

```
<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="-1" 
multiple="true" value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.getTabs()}" var="r">
```

works only if there is no value attribut of accordionPanel

thanks for any help.

I have primesfaces 3.3.1

Comment: And the value is set to? Please post how you create the value (Java code).

Comment: @siebz0r: getTabs is just a function in view scopped mangedBean that return a List of Tab with attributes code and label. and then I use label in tab title like this <p:tab title="#{r.libelle}">

Comment: It works fine with p:accordionPanel activeIndex="x"

Comment: For PrimeFaces 6.0, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41960522/1599699

Answer (score 39):

Using 'null' worked for me:  `<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="null">`

I'm using PF 3.5 and setting activeIndex to null leaves the tabs closed by default.

Answer (score 9):

I am using PF 3.5 and with this version I have realized that if I give a negative number for `activeIndex` greater than the number of tabs in the p:accordianPanel, it collapses all the tabs. E.g.

```xml
<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="-2">
   <p:tab title="Hello">
   </p:tab>
   <p:tab title="World">
   </p>
 </p:accordionPanel>
```

Shows the accordian with all tabs collapsed. Let me know if this works for you or if you have found another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by simple lefting it empty.
This way: `activeIndex=""`

Comment: Doing this breaks the js later, at least with 3.5. No possibility of opening it. @John Brown 's answer goes better.

Answer (score 2):

In my scenario setting activeIndex="-1" or activeIndex="null" or activeIndex="-" or activeIndex="" did not work.

**I returned -1 from manager bean and it worked. Getter always returns -1 and setter does nothing.**

```
activeIndex="#{managerBean.activeTabIndices}"
```

Comment: p.s. I needed all tabs to be always closed initially.

Comment: Hey! It looks like you did not read my post attentively. It is not a comment or a question any thing. I gave another possible solution to the problem already being discussed.

Comment: None of the previous solutions worked for me so I thought how I solved it might help someone.

Comment: Sorry. I retract my NAA-flag

Answer (score 1):

Try `<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="null" multiple="true" ...>`

If you write anything like `<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="x" multiple="true" ...>`, primefaces produce javascript error "ReferenceError: x is not defined".
The function obviously expects a valid number as activeIndex, but is able to deal with "null" without error.

Comment: sorry, I wanted to write three dots and the system misinterpretted the entity. I fixed it, &hellip; wasn't ment to be there.